# Xcode how to disable insert mode cursor on single or double quotes?

Tags: xcode

When I type a single or double quotes it highlighted like on photo. Xcode Version 7.3.1. Help how to disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody have the same situation you need to change input source from U.S. international - PC to another one